# (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range

Tags: python

I have a list of list of points called pts2. I want to create a new list of points taken from pts2 that satisfy certain conditions. However, I keep receiving error. I don't know what went wrong

```
pts2 = [[point1, point2],[point3, point4], [point5,point6]]
pts3 = []

for i in (0,pts2.Count):
    if (pts2[i][1].X - pts2[i][0].X) < 0 or (pts2[i][1].Y - pts2[i][0].Y) < 0 or (pts2[i][1].Z - pts2[i][0].Z) < 0:
    pts3.append(None) #dont add any point
```

> Error: Runtime error (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range: 64

Comment: Can u access this item `pts2[i][2]` ??...List indexing starts from 0.

Comment: Weird, after making up some points your code raises `AttributeError` when I run it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I managed to fix it thou.

Answer (score 3):

Your point lists are all only 2 long, but you're referencing pts2[i][2], which is the third position. This will obviously throw an exception, because your points don't have a third position.

Comment: Oh sorry, my careless mistake. it should be [0] and [1]. However now it reports Runtime error (IndexOutOfRangeException): index out of range: 64

Comment: @NguyenMinhChau You need to revise your code and provide a better [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because based on how you put your original question together, this answer is correct. Make sure what you post as a question is a proper representation of your actual problem.